# Customized Map Icons - issue with unwanted space in icon image (css/html)

Tags: html, css, icons

I've created custom map icons to replace the standard set in Leaflet maps for a Drupal site on which I'm working. I created these icons in Photoshop, and trimmed the final image to a pixel between the image and the end of the canvas (to avoid any problems due to the transparent background pixels). This is all well and good, I've uploaded the file to the map and it is working fine, **EXCEPT**: for some reason I'm getting extra space in the image.

html is the following:

```
<div class="leaflet-div-icon3">
    <img src="example_image.png" height="90" width="90" border="0"/>    
</div>`
```

The CSS `.leaflet-div-icon3` is completely empty - it's just a trick we used to be able to source the image correctly with the Leaflet module.

So, the image box is 90x90 pixels but the actual icon accounts for only maybe a tenth of that space.

I cannot seem to figure this one out so if any of you can think of something I may have overlooked, I would greatly appreciate feedback. I would've provided an image but I need 10 rep to do so :(

Comment: What are the pixel dimensions for the image without the definition?

Comment: Pixel dimensions were 125x219 prior to the html definition. But I've figured this out and to be honest the solution was trivial and will not be helpful to others so I'll likely be deleting this post. Anyhow, thanks for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 0):

Blind guess : add `display: block` to class `.leaflet-div-icon3` in the CSS stylesheet. Better post some code if you want us to give you an accurate answer ... or a link to your site ?

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't be more specific with my question - there really wasn't much code to show! However, I've managed to figure this one out myself and I don't think others will be finding the solution very helpful so I will likely be deleting the post. Regardless, I very much appreciate your willingness to help!